# Why is interval timer shooting unavailable in every mode on my Nikon Z6?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, intervalometer

This is driving me a bit crazy. I'm using a Nikon Z6 with the 24-70 F4. I cannot access the interval timer shooting menu (nor the time-lapse movie or focus shift shooting); the camera insists "This option is not available at current settings or in the cameras current state". It remains greyed out. Yet I have tried all the settings I can think of, RAW, jpeg, manual focus, shooting in video mode, a variety of release modes... nothing will make it accessible.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Mark that one down to "enthusiasm to try it out wins over sitting down to read the dull 400-page manual every time" ;) You perhaps ought to actually make that into an answer, for some fabulous invisible internet points & the chance for other people to google it in future.

Comment: Hi Jon, welcome to Photo-SE. We've all been there beating our heads against dumb things like that! Echoing @Tetsujin's comment, would you mind moving your edit/resolution to an answer to your question, and even mark your answer as the accepted answer? It's absolutely ok to ask and answer your own question here at Stack Exchange. We like having answered and accepted answers here. Thanks, and happy shooting! =)

Answer (score 7):

Turns out you have to set the cameras time zone and time.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem, the "Time-Lapse movie" was grayed out and could not be used.  Turn out to be the XQD memory card was not in the camera slot.  Time-lapse can only be activated if the XQD card is well inserted in the Z6 Camera.